# Angular cli ng create Error : Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using Angular Cli to create component.

I am using this command:

```
ng g c CarComponent --module=./views/administration/administration.module.ts --spec=false --flat
```

I got the error:

```
Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
```

My Angular version is:

```
Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 12.18.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.2.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core            10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.2.0
@angular/cdk                    10.2.5
@schematics/angular             10.2.0
@schematics/update              0.1002.0
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      3.9.7
```

Anyone could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The option to skip spec file should be `--skipTests=true`. Check the [documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component).
Therefore I think your command should be change to the following.

```
ng g c CarComponent --module=./views/administration/administration.module.ts --skipTests=true --flat
```